# Dualbooting doesn't work, defaults to windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

**Edit:**
I can not boot from the installation media in UEFI mode. I have disabled all of the fast/enhanced/accelerated startup options from intel/microsoft, I have disabled all CSM, I have configured the install media with rufus, as a GPT partitioned fat32 DD image mode (I have also tried ISO image mode). No matter what I do, grub and ubuntu can't latch on to the EFI partition on my hard drive for some reason.

I have sucessfully installed Ubuntu but I can only boot from it when I press f12 after the motherboard beep, then another beep occurs after which I press f8. This has a 50% chance of getting me directly into some sort of PXE process. I wait for that to time out and tada, Ubuntu boots. Needless to say, that's not very ideal.

When booting without interfering user input, it just directly loads windows 8.

Could I possibly fix this by setting the Device for boot loader installation to
/dev/sda/[efi partition]? I don't want to brick my computer and make it unbootable.

**Original post**

So I just got done installing the most recent LTF version of Ubuntu on my (only) hdd harddisk.

On windows, I shrunk the C partition to leave about 400gb for Ubuntu.

Then, when installing Ubuntu from my installation media (USB flash drive) I made the following partitions:

`dev/sda9 411238MB ext4, mount: /`

`dev/sda10 8192MB swap`

During the setup I used the default boot loader installation path

```
Device for boot loader installation:
/dev/sda ATA ST1000DM003-1CH1 (1.0 TB)
```

I went ahead with the installation process, and after a while it prompted me that the install was successful, and that I could continue trying Ubuntu out, or to reboot. So I rebooted, and now I can't actually get into Ubuntu.

I'm using a prefab computer, if that helps.

```
Model: MP Elite Power I3-3220
Motherboard: mp MS-7797
BIOS/EUFI (not sure which) firmware: M7797W08-mp2.20F
```

My harddisk should looks like this: (some partitions ommited)

```
/dev
 /sda5 ntfs //windows
 /sda9 ext4 //ubuntu
 /sda10 swap
```

When my computer boots, I press <kbd>F8</kbd>, this brings up this menu:

```
Please select boot device:
[Enter setup]
```

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, it tells me to insert a valid media or to reboot.

So now what? My computer isn't bricked, it just refuses to load to anything else than windows. I do not get an OS selection prompt when booting, and I can't seem to generate such prompt myself.

Comment: Of those omitted partitions is one of them EFI?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes. Windows disk management shows it as 100mb, second partition, at the time the Ubuntu partition thingy showed a 104MB fat32 partition at sda2, probably it.

Comment: Then it's a UEFI system with Windows installed in that mode, as expected. You may have installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I need to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode? I don't recall such install option, do I need special tools for that?

Comment: How it boots is how it installs. To avoid mistakes disable Legacy/CSM in UEFI settings. Otherwise you'll have 2 selections fir the USB stick, one will say UEFI. And yes, reinstalling is probably the most effective and faster solution.

Comment: I can't disable CSM, my graphics card (gtx 750) needs video OpROM = legacy, otherwise the motherboard just beeps error sounds on boot. Al the other options are set to UEFI.

Comment: So make sure to select the USB option that mentions UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your grub.conf file to order your boot options however you want.  Use your favorite editor (VIM, nano, pico, etc) and just put Ubuntu at the top of the list or Windows at the bottom of the list and reboot your machine to verify the options are listed how you like.

Comment: Thanks, but see my edit